# AEM project release build

Tags: maven, aem, aem-6

I am interested to see how people are doing release builds for an AEM project:

- using the maven release plugin that is in pom.xml OOTB for this archtype
- custom process using other maven plugins (build-helper plugin, version plugin)

Pros/cons for each option?
what is the release numbering mechanism that you use?
how is the patching done?
do you use a release branching mechanism?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The OOTB maven build configuration from the archetype is good enough and extensively used across all the AEM projects I have been involved in. The versioning can be handled by modifying the version in the pom.xml

Comment: I know that version can be changed in pom.xml, but how do you handle the patching process and numbering with this plugin? so for example we need to follow the convention:
major version increased for major release, minor one increased for every release, and the patch for prod bugfix - with maven release plugin I can't control this aspect because it always increases the last digit of the version.